# iPhone Objective C: Method to generate a new object and return it, seems to generate the old object

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing a game, and I have to create "Obstacles", I created a method that randomly generates the obstacles, and returns them. At first, in the method, I did something like this,

```
Obstacle newObstacle = [[Obstacle alloc] init];
[newObstacle setFrame:CGRectMake(randX, randY, 50, 50)];
return newObstacle;
```

but after some debugging, I found out it was returning the same object, with the same address every time it was called, so I did not get a new unique object.

So then I changed the code to:

```
return [[Obstacle alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(randX, randY, 50, 50)];
```

but the problem still seems to be there, and here is the best part, when I try to debug, if I put a breakpoint within the loop that this method is being called (so that it pauses a bit before it calls the generator method) then I get new unique obstacles, but if I let the loop run and generate them all, I inspect the array and find out that they are all the same objects.

Any clue as to what is going on here?
Let me know if I need to provide more code.

Comment: Show the code where you put them in the array.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can show us your loop code that generates them all

Comment: Hopefully your Obstacle class isn't a singleton class. If you written that class confirm it, and if its open source lib, go thru the code once please.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to write:

```
Obstacle *newObstacle = [[Obstacle alloc] init];
```

with a *

Comment: If this were an actual error in the code, rather than just a typo in the question, what would happen?

Comment: yea it was just a typo in the question, I had the asterisk in the program..... I am finding out that it actually isn't the problem I thought it is, the objects are returning with different addresses in memory, they just have the same frame set, even though the x and y should be random... I will have to find out why this is happening... and I'll update in a bit

Comment: So, I found out why this was happening. The time function was returning an integer that was too large for the random seed function, so when there was only a tiny change in the time, it wouldn't actually change the seed. In short, the time function overloaded the seed. So, to solve this, all I had to do was mod the value down by something like this

Answer (score 0):

Since when you debug you see a new object the problem must be later when it is used, the object used is the old one.